# Troubleshooting simple beginner assembly code

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

I'm trying to learn Assembly coding for an 8051 microcontroller, and at the moment I'm just trying to run a simple program to light an LED when a button is pressed.

When I run the circuit in a simulator, the led doesnt light up. I believe the issue to be with the code though I'm not sure where. Can anyone help?

```
ORG 0
SJMP START

ORG 40H

    START: JNB P1.0, START
           ACALL light
           SJMP START


    light: SETB P1.4
           RETI

END
```

Comment: maybe you need to clear the bit not set it.  Some boards you need to source voltage to the led, supply the high side, some boards you need to sink, supply the ground.  My 8051 is rusty I assume if there is a SETB there is probably  a CLRB, try that see what happens.  There could be other basic things involved like enabling the gpio pin as an output, releasing clocks/reset on the gpio block, etc...

Comment: you probably need to set the pin as an output, 8051s are not all created identically so some of the detail is chip/vendor specific, I looked at some of my simple blink the led 8051 code and for the chip I was using it did need some setup to make the port/pin an output...